# No ubuntu 12.04 toolbar when installed through VMware workstation

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 inside VMware workstation.  I'm new to both VMware and Ubuntu.  When I open Ubuntu up, there's no menu anywhere.  Is I move my mouse around, I can see that it's highlighting toolbar options on the leftside, but I can't tell what those options are.  I can click and open things up, but that isn't very helpful.  I've tried changing the background image, but that doesn't fix it.  Any idea how to make the toolbar show up?  Is it because I'm running it through VMware workstation?

Comment: Have you installed VMware Tools?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. You have two options:

1. Log in using Ubuntu 2D

or

1. Turn off 3D Acceleration in the VMware. 
   On the menu bar go to VM > Settings > Display > Uncheck Accelerate 3D graphics. ;)On the menu bar go to VM > Settings > Display > Uncheck Accelerate 3D graphics.